# What is the fastest way to backup an Azure SQL Server Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql, azure-storage

I have a medium sized database that is running within Azure. It is about 30GB. I used the Azure console to do an export to an Azure storage account- that seems to be the way to do it. However, it has so far taken 3 hours to backup 25% and has utilisation of the S1 20DTU database at 100%. Is there a better way to get a local copy of an Azure SQL Database?